# How to get value from var Variable?

Tags: c#

in my wpf project form ,
i have variable Items 'var' type  which content DataGridRow as

```
{ Id = 26, Challan_No = 2014CH 10026, Organization = dd, Organization_Name = Unique Art, Date = 30-Nov-14 12:00:00 AM }
```

So i want to get "Chalaan_No" value(2014CH 10026)

Comment: `var` actually have a type that is inferred from the code, so there is nothing different than working with a variable declared explicitly of that type. Is this instead a `dynamic` or other type?

Comment: var isn't a type, it is just implicitly typed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx.

Comment: I'm guessing this is an anonymous type and that's why the OP doesn't know what to call it.

Comment: then.. how can i get value from select row in wpf Datagrid, DatagridRow are selected by Using Checked box.....

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a class to represent your DataRows, this should get you started:

```
    private void TestDgvFilter()
    {
        DataGrid DG = new DataGrid();
        DG.Items.Filter = new Predicate<object>(Filter);
    }

    private bool Filter(object t)
    {
        DataItem d = t as DataItem;
        return (d.Challan_No == "2014CH 10026");
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Class that represents your data grid row items
    /// </summary>
    private class DataItem
    {
        public string Id;
        public string Challan_No;
        public string Organization;
        public string Organization_Name;
        public string Date;
    }
```

Reference:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833072(v=vs.95).aspx